# PHP - how to set session onClick in tag <a> using get request

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have this code, I need to set session onclick with tag `<a>` using get request on another page.

For example, if I click item 4 it to send the value to URL and set session onclick link.

```
    while(list($product_id,$product_title,$product_name) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$product_id."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='product_detail.php?sendVar=".$product_id."' onclick='".$_SESSION['kuy'] = $product_id."'>".$product_title."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$product_name."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Sorry i'm not good at english

Comment: anchor tag doesn't have attribute `onclick`

Comment: How should I use it.

Comment: You should include the script in your `product_detail.php`

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` event works only with javascript in browser

In your code you rewrite `kuy` session for each item in the loop. When your page is rendered, you can find `kuy` with last `product_id`

If you want to set session with `product_id`, you should do it in your `product_detail.php`
Here you can fetch `product_id` from `$_GET['sendVar']` and set this value to `$_SESSION['kuy']`

Comment: I know that way. but when user change value in url webpage will change data on web. Is there a way to make it look the same when the value is change?